# Show record value as a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
    X    |      Y      |  Z
---------+-------------+-----
3136     |   2014-03   |  A
700      |   2014-03   |  B
531      |   2014-03   |  C
1575     |   2014-03   |  D
2776     |   2014-04   |  A
1200     |   2014-04   |  B
148      |   2014-04   |  C
903      |   2014-04   |  D
```

And i want to convert this table to something like:

```
Date        |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D
------------+------+------+------+------
2014-03     | 3136 | 700  | 531  | 1575
2014-04     | 2776 | 1200 | 148  | 903
```

How can I do it with a single select?

Comment: what if its E,F...Z  in the Z values ?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT y as Date,
SUM(CASE WHEN Z='A' THEN X ELSE 0 END) as A,
SUM(CASE WHEN Z='B' THEN X ELSE 0 END) as B,
SUM(CASE WHEN Z='C' THEN X ELSE 0 END) as C,
SUM(CASE WHEN Z='D' THEN X ELSE 0 END) as D
FROM table
GROUP BY y
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
    Y as date
  , MAX( case Z when 'A' then X else null end ) as `A`
  , MAX( case Z when 'B' then X else null end ) as `B`
  , MAX( case Z when 'C' then X else null end ) as `C`
  , MAX( case Z when 'D' then X else null end ) as `D`
  -- add more if requird
from table_name
group by Y
```